# Discord.js guildCreate and guildDelete events are not fired

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

**What is my problem?**
Sometimes I don't get `guildCreate` and `guildDelete` events.

**Does the problem occur every time?**
No. About 40% of the time it works without a problem.

**Do I get an error message?** No. No error message is fired.

**My code:**

```js
const DiscordServer = require('./backend-lib/models/DiscordServer');

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [ Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD ] });

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('ready');
});

/* It's listening to the event `guildCreate` and then it's creating a new document in the database. */
client.once('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
  console.log('create');
});

/* It's listening to the event `guildDelete` and then it's deleting the document in the database. */
client.once('guildDelete', async (guild) => {
  console.log('delete', guild.id);
});

/* It's connecting to SQS and listening to it. */
client.once('ready', async () => {
   require('./services/helper');
});

client.login(conf.discord.token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using the correct intents. However, you're using `client.once`, that adds a one-time listener for your `guildCreate` and `guildDelete` events. The first time the event is triggered, the listener is removed and the callback function is fired. As the listener gets removed, the callback won't run again unless you restart your bot.

If you want to trigger these events more than once, you can use the `.on()` method:

```js
client.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
  console.log('create');
});

client.on('guildDelete', async (guild) => {
  console.log('delete', guild.id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That was definitely a stupid mistake on my part.